# Exception in "JavaFX Application Thread" when using JavaFX control

Tags: java, swing, javafx-8, pane

I am initializing a generic JavaFX 8 ComboBox with Enum values as follows:

```
ObservableList<MyEnumClass> myValues = FXCollections
        .observableArrayList(MyEnumClass.FIRST_ENUM, 
                MyEnumClass.SECOND_ENUM, MyEnumClass.THIRD_ENUM);
myEnumComboBox = new ComboBox<MyEnumClass>(myValues);
```

A test application shows the ComboBox with the Enum values as expected and selecting other values also works fine. But one thing puzzels me: Even though I can not observe any apparent malfunction, my Eclipse console nevertheless notifies me about an exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" whenever I select a new value from the ComboBox's menu. The exception seems to be related to the native JavaFX code that hides the ComboBox's popup control:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEvent.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.UngrabEvent.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode$10.handle(Unknown Source)
        [9 lines omitted]
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.focusUngrab(Unknown Source)
        [4 lines omitted]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyFocusUngrab(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinWindow._ungrabFocus(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.ungrabFocus(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.ungrabFocus(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.decreaseFocusGrabCounter(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.PopupWindow.handleAutohideActivation(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.PopupWindow.impl_visibleChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.Window.hide(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.stage.PopupWindow.hide(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.hide(Unknown Source)
        [44 lines omitted]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can somebody explain what exactly is happening here and what I can or should do about it?

---

**EDIT** - The exception was caused by a leftover [SwingNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) from some earlier experiment on the same Pane as the ComboBox. Deleting the SwingNode made the exception vanish.

Comment: Hard to say, but it looks to be an issue with events trickling down from JavaFX to Swing's AWT event system.

Comment: Why do you have a [SwingNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html)? What are you doing? Can you supply an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which is both minimal and executable?